# Facebook api PHP: Posting to another users page feed not working

Tags: php, facebook

I have been trying to post a message and image on a page feed. I keep getting the error message

> (#1) An error occured while creating the share.

This only happens if someone else tries to post. If I, the owner of the page tries to post it is successful.

So my question is: Is it possible to post to another users page feed?

I have done a lot of research into this but I cant seem to find a plausible solution.

Here is the code I am using to post the message:

```
<?php

class Photo_contest_helper extends Facebook
{
    private $_key = '***********';
    private $_secret = '***************';

    private $_page_id = '387228561388254';

    public $fb_login_url;
    public $fb_logout_url;

    public $image_id;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->connect();

        $image_id = $this->save_image();

        if( !!$image_id ) {
            $this->image_id = $image_id;
            $this->push_to_facebook( $image_id );
        }
    }

    public function save_image()
    {
        $image_id = NULL;

        if ( !!$_POST[ "image" ] || !!$_FILES ) {
            $image_id = Image_helper::save_one( $_POST[ "image" ] );
        }

        return $image_id;
    }

    public function push_to_facebook( $image_id )
    {
        $access_token = $this->get_page_access_token();

        $this->publish_photo( $access_token );
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        parent::__Construct( array( 'appId' => $this->_key, 'secret' => $this->_secret ) );

        $user = $this->getUser();

        if( !$user ) {
            $this->fb_login_url = $this->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'manage_pages,publish_actions,publish_stream,status_update' ) );
        }
        else {
            $this->fb_logout_url = $this->getLogoutUrl( array( 'next' => 'http://stormtest.co.uk/' . DIRECTORY . "home/logout" ) );
        }
    }

    public function get_page_access_token()
    {
        $accounts = $this->api( '/me/accounts', 'get' );
        $access_token = NULL;

        foreach ( $accounts[ 'data' ] as $account ) {
            if ( $account[ 'id' ] == $this->_page_id ) {
                $access_token = $account[ 'access_token' ];
            }
        }

        return $access_token;
    }

    public function publish_photo( $access_token = "" )
    {

        $params = array( 'message' => 'Competition entry',
                         'link' => 'http://stormtest.co.uk/' . DIRECTORY . '_admin/assets/uploads/images/' . $this->get_image(),
                         'caption' => 'This is my competition entry',
                         'picture' => 'http://stormtest.co.uk/' . DIRECTORY . '_admin/assets/uploads/images/' . $this->get_image() );

        if( !!$access_token ) {
            $params[ 'access_token' ] = $access_token;
        }


        try {
            $this->api( '/' . $this->_page_id . '/feed', 'post', $params );
        }
        catch( FacebookApiException $e ) {
            die( print_r( $e ) );
        }
    }

    public function get_image()
    {
        $image_model = new Image_model();
        $image_model->find( $this->image_id );

        return $image_model->attributes[ 'imgname' ];
    } 
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not post to another user’s wall any more via API. Only possibility is to use the Feed/Share dialogs, and thereby having the post triggered by your active user himself. (_“I have done a lot of research into this”_ … I find it hard to believe that.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the JavaScript SDK to share content to the page. Posting to others' walls via the API has been disabled:

```
FB.ui( {
    method: 'feed',
    to: '387228561388254',
    name: "Facebook API: Tracking Shares using the JavaScript SDK",
    link: "https://www.webniraj.com/2013/05/11/facebook-api-tracking-shares-using-the-javascript-sdk/",
    picture: "https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/557969.png",
    caption: "Tracking Facebook Shares on your website or application is a useful way of seeing how popular your articles are with your readers. In order to tracking Shares, you must used the Facebook JavaScript SDK."
}, callback );
```

Use the `to` field in the above code to set the page_id, and change the other attributes accordingly (but don't change `method`).